# getResourceAsStream() returning null

Tags: java, android, jar, getresource

I have a java .jar library, and from there i'm trying to access a file of my Android project
with:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/folder/data.txt");
someMethod(inputStream); // inputStream is null
```

But the `inputStream` is always `null`. I'm confused about where should i put my `/folder/data.txt` in order to
be able to find it from the .jar.

From within the .jar project i can find the data.txt, doing the following in eclipse:

```
MyProject > properties > java build path > libraries > Add class folder
```

and this code:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.txt"); // without the folder
```

This is the structure of the Java Project:

```
MyJavaProject

  - src
    - com.example
      - something.java
      - folder
           - data.txt
```

Now, inside the Android Project i try to do the same but i keep getting null (inputStream):

```
MyAndroidProject

  - src
    - several packages
    - folder
       - data.txt
  - libs
     - my jar
```

Where should i put my data.txt? or should i change something in my .jar

I've read a lot of similar questions but i haven't found a solution. I've also read about `getResourceAsStream()` but i'm obviously not getting it.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way, versus using Android resources or assets?

Comment: You've missed off the quotation marks. I'm assuming they were there in your original code, or else it wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: you are mistaking Resources with Assets. Resources are the xml's, pngs, etc.. under /res/ . You probably want to put your stuff under "assets" and then use the assets interface to load them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResourceAsStream()` isn't terribly useful in android.  It refers to files embedded in a JAR or classpath container, not android Resources.  You probably want to use the android `assets` feature instead.  You can simply place the asset file (`"data.txt"`) under your project's `assets/` directory.

To get an `InputStream` for the asset, you can use the `AssetsManager`, like this (error handling is omitted for clarity:

```
// get the assets manager from your activity or `Context`
final AssetsManager am = getAssets();
final InputStream   in = am.open("data.txt");
// do stuff with the input stream
```

Another approach is to use `Resources` instead, but this depends on the contents of `data.txt`  Resources are intended for data types that android knows how to load and parse, such as drawables, strings, and various xml files.  Assets are for raw data that you are going to read and parse yourself.

Comment: Isn't this just sidestepping the question? getResourceAsStream may still be useful on Android, e.g. for cross platform libraries...

Comment: @StefanHaustein I don't know, this is a really old answer ;-)  Feel free to edit if you have any improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Resouses in android means drawables, values ..  etc folders.

For text file create a folder named raw and put your data file there.

Try to send the path to the library method as as data.txt then as raw/data.txt